# React input field states wont update after handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the semantic UI library along with react and was following their example for form input here

https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form

(The one at the very very bottom btw)

The forms update their text fine and I've tested to see if the states are updating and they are! However when I want to set the submitted/Width,Height,Color states to the other ones it doesn't work! It gives me this warning in the console.

```
./src/components/Holder/HolderInput.jsx
  Line 33:  'submittedWidth' is assigned a value but never used   no-unused-vars
  Line 34:  'submittedHeight' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 35:  'submittedColor' is assigned a value but never used   no-unused-vars
```

Code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Form} from 'semantic-ui-react';

class HolderInput extends Component {
  state = {
    width: '',
    height: '',
    color: '',
    submittedWidth: '',
    submittedHeight: '',
    submittedColor: ''
  };

  handleChange = (e, {name, value}) => this.setState({[name]: value});

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log('Called handleSubmit()');
    const {width, height, color} = this.state;
    console.log('Width Value: ' + width);
    console.log('height Value: ' + height);
    console.log('color Value: ' + color);

    console.log('SubmittedWidth Value: ' + this.state.submittedWidth);

    this.setState({submittedWidth: width, submittedHeight: height, submittedColor: color}),
    () => {
      console.log('SubmittedWidth: ' + this.state.submittedWidth);
      this.setState({width: '', height: '', color: ''});
    }

  }

  render() {
    const {
      width,
      height,
      color,
      submittedWidth,
      submittedHeight,
      submittedColor
    } = this.state;

    return (<Form className='holder-input-form' size={'huge'} inverted="inverted" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

      <Form.Group widths={'equal'}>
        <Form.Input placeholder='45px...' name='height' value={height} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <Form.Input placeholder='25px...' name='width' value={width} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Input placeholder='exp. #ffffff or white' name='color' value={color} onChange={this.handleChange}/>

      <Form.Button inverted="inverted" size={'big'} color='violet'>Update It!</Form.Button>
    </Form>);
  }
}

export default HolderInput;
```

After running this piece of code it does console log the color, height and width. It doesn't even acknowledge the submitted states however. It doesn't return any errors and it doesn't empty the input fields which indicates that the first setState isn't being completed but I don't know why....

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It does seem like you are not using those variables.

Comment: Well this component is later going to be used in another to control a divs width and height but for now I just wanted to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cosmichero2025, your method is correct, only some typo, can you please change the following section and test it:

```
    this.setState({submittedWidth: width, submittedHeight: height, submittedColor: color},
  () => {
    console.log('SubmittedWidth: ' + this.state.submittedWidth);
    this.setState({width: '', height: '', color: ''});
  }
)
```

Comment: OP is using `setState` callback to console which is the right way of doing it.

Comment: Oh it returned with this "inside render => SubmittedWidth: the width" so it setting the value? Then why does it not fire the code after the this.setState

Comment: omg i was dumb and mixed up the parentheses and brackets!!!!!!! thank you for noticing my stupidity XD